# Художник-осень - допустимо ли?

Tags: род

Здравствуйте,

Насколько грамотно или нет будет сказать Художник-Осень (причём в контексте женского рода, т. е. действия все будут - "нарисовала" итд)? Допустима только форма Художница-Осень или нет и какие правила вообще есть для подобных случаев?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, "художник-осень" и женский род сказуемого будут сочетаться плохо, хотя с точки зрения выразительности ямб данного выражения выглядит лучше, нежели "художница-осень". Как варианты решения могу предложить или сделать осень "мужчиной", или переставить слова в выражении - *осень-художница*, тогда вместо ямба будет дактиль и выразительность не пострадает.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен, осень-художница - намного лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Допустимо.
Стилистически я бы сохранил мужской род. Заглавные не нужны.
Тут есть тонкость, подобные сочетания бывают двух типов, в зависимости от смысловой   составляющих слов.
Счет-фактура - он, кафе-клуб - тоже он. 
Такие слова и склоняются по-разному.  
//----  
Разве женщина обязана быть художницей, не художником?

x x x
Моим стихам, написанным так рано,
Что и не знала я, что я – поэт,
Сорвавшимся, как брызги из фонтана,
Как искры из ракет,
Ворвавшимся, как маленькие черти,
В святилище, где сон и фимиам,
Моим стихам о юности и смерти
– Нечитанным стихам! –
Разбросанным в пыли по магазинам
(Где их никто не брал и не берет!),
Моим стихам, как драгоценным винам,
Настанет свой черед.
(Марина)

Answer (score 1):

Гроздья рябины на ветках забыты,

Желтые краски берез потускнели,

На тротуарах, дождями размытых,

Осень рисует свои акварели.

Листьями красит зеленые  ели,

Небо штрихует косыми дождями,

Будто рисуя  свои акварели,

Осень-художник прощается с нами.